# save values of foreign key django

Tags: python, django

I want savevalues of foreign key model in view fuctions, this my models, forms, and views.
models.py:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND0Ya.png)

Forms.py:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WdHp.png)

View.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7B5T.png)

Comment: Hi! Just a quick note, we need to have the code written in as per the best practices outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can save the object beeing created like : object = depto.save() then get the id like depto.id